# xml doesnt match xsd schema - why?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I need xml to match XSD schema but it doesnt match. What can be wrong in XSD schema? Something not right with xsi:type="...". I may miss something. Hope you can notice what is wrong. I have been trying to use xsd validate online and fix it but doesnt work. So I give up and decide to write here. Your help much appreciated. Thanks!

**Here is XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ValidatorList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <FieldValidator xsi:type="RequiredFieldValidator"  PropertyName="BankTransactionNumber">
   <Next xsi:type="AsciiValidator" />
  </FieldValidator>
  <FieldValidator xsi:type="RequiredFieldValidator"  PropertyName="CurrencyIndicator">
   <Next xsi:type="StringLengthValidator" MaxLength="3" MinLength="3">
   <Next xsi:type="AlphaValidator" />
  </Next>
 </FieldValidator>
</ValidatorList>
```

**XSD Schema for this XML:**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="ValidatorList">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FieldValidator" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Next" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Next" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="Next" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                              <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="DecimalPlaces"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                          </xs:simpleContent>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MaxLength" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MinLength" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="AllowedValues" use="optional"/>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MaxLength" use="optional"/>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MinLength" use="optional"/>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="DefaultValue" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="RegEx" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="PropertyName" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="DefaultValue" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="TypeProperty" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Regex" use="optional"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**I got error message like this:**

```
Error - Line 4, 39: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 39; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'AsciiValidator' to a type definition for element 'Next'.
Error - Line 6, 87: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 87; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'RequiredFieldValidator' to a type definition for element 'FieldValidator'.
Error - Line 7, 72: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 72; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'StringLengthValidator' to a type definition for element 'Next'.
Error - Line 8, 41: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 41; cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'AlphaValidator' to a type definition for element 'Next'.
```

Comment: So? Where is your `AsciiValidator` type defined? I can't see in in the schema. Perhaps try changing all the `xsi:type` to `FieldValidator` (the only one you have defined).

Comment: it is string type. im not sure how to correct xsd schema...

Comment: `AsciiValidator` is a string type?

Comment: yes it is because there is inside a xml "AsciiValidor" is a string type. there are different names like AsciiValidtor, RequiredFieldValidator etc inside xml so all of them are string type. You mean i should change from xsi:type to FieldValidator="AsciiValidator" in a xml?

Comment: `xsi:type` points to a complex type of the given name. This means that `AsciiValidator` should be declared in your XSD the same way that `FieldValidator` is. Alas, it is not, and that's what causes the error. What I meant was changing  `xsi:type="RequiredFieldValidator"` into  `xsi:type="FieldValidator"` since that's the only type you have declared. This may or may not solve the issue, however, and it certainly does not explain where all these missing type declarations are gone.

Comment: well i cannot change RequiredFieldValidator to FieldValidator. seems there is no solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsi:type` attribute is intended to be used when you have a hierarchy of *named* types in a schema and an element whose declared type is the base type but whose actual type is one of the derived types.  The archetypal example would be an `address` type with subtypes `usAddress` and `ukAddress`

In your schema the `FieldValidator` and `Next` elements are declared using anonymous nested `<complexType>` definitions rather than named types, so there's no way you could have other types derived from these, so no sense in using `xsi:type`.  I would structure the schema differently, using top-level named types:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="FieldValidatorType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Next" type="FieldValidatorType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="PropertyName" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="RequiredFieldValidator">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="FieldValidatorType" />
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="AsciiValidator">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="FieldValidatorType" />
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="StringLengthValidator">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="FieldValidatorType">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MaxLength" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="MinLength" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- and similar complexType declarations for the other types such as
       AlphaValidator -->

  <xs:element name="ValidatorList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <!-- define the FieldValidator element by referring to the base
             FieldValidatorType, instance documents can use xsi:type to
             substitute subtypes such as StringLengthValidator -->
        <xs:element name="FieldValidator" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                    type="FieldValidatorType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As well as making the `xsi:type` attributes work properly, this has the advantage of tying the different facets to their respective validator types (e.g. `MaxLength` is only valid for a `StringLengthValidator`) and also supporting arbitrary depths of `Next` nesting (because the type definition is recursive).

Comment: It is almost working but there is one error message i got : Error - Line 29, 103: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 103; src-element.3: Element 'FieldValidator' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element.

Comment: @user235973457 the error message says it all - the `type="FieldValidatorType"` on the `<xs:element name="FieldValidator">` inside `ValidatorList` is _instead of_ the nested `<complexType>`, not _as well as_.

Comment: @user235973457 I've tried to make things clearer by giving a single complete `<xs:schema>`.